# AlertDialog inside Fragment is not closed when button is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

I have Fragment inside which I'm using AlertDialog. There is no problem in closing of AlertDialog in Activity but when I used same code in Fragment, the AlertDialog doesns't closes **until I press button minimum 3 times**.

Also after I press Ok button, alertDialog freezes for 2 sec then Toast msg are displayed. But dialog doesn't closes.

I also tried using `dialog.dismiss()`. But problem remains same.

Here is my CheckFragment class.

```
public class ChecckFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener {
    private static AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private Context context
     @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         context = this.getActivity();     
       }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //other codes....
     View btnCheck = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveNew);
     btnCheck.setOnClickListener(listener);
      }
   private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         createCheckBox();
         alertDialog.show();
         }
    }
   //Function to create checkBox.
   private void createCheckBox(){
    final CharSequence[] checkSequences = {" Low "," Mid "," High "," Very High"};
    final ArrayList<Integer> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    AlertDialog.Builder checkBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    checkBuilder.setTitle("Select School Leaving Reason");
    checkBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(checkSequences, null, new         DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                itemList.add(indexSelected);
            } else if (itemList.contains(indexSelected)) {
                itemList.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
            }
        }
    });

    checkBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int str : itemList){
             sb.append(",");    //separating contents using semi colon
                sb.append(str); 
            }
            sb.deleteCharAt(0); //Delete chatacter at 0.
            String string = sb.toString();
         Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Items:"+ sb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        alertDialog.dismiss();//Called dismiss here but dialog doesnt closes
        }
    });
    checkBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();//Called dismiss here too but dialog doesnt closes
        }
    });

    alertDialog = checkBuilder.create();

}
}
```

I'm really stucked dudes. Please Help!!!!

Comment: You must call alertDialog = checkBuilder.create(); and then alertDialog.show();

Comment: I tried it but my alert dialog still doesnt close.

Comment: can You update Your code above?

Comment: You can use DialogFragment instead of AlertDialog. It may helpful for you.

Comment: are you getting any error ?

Comment: I have made little changes to my code using create() and then show(). Now alertDialog closes if I press button more than 3 times. Its really weird.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ no error just freezing of alertDialog, then toast are displayed but dialog doesnt closes

Comment: Try ma answer.It's working at ma side :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

`AlertDialog alertDialog= new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();`

then, 
Just call  `alertDialog.dismiss();`

will sure work.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialize alerDialogBuilder as `checkBuilder` and closing AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder checkBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
```

try to close checkBuilder

```
checkBuilder.dismiss();
```

Comment: checkbuiler doesn't support dismiss() method so I used AlertDialog.  above code runs fine in activity problem occurs only in fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a silly mistake. You need to dismiss `DialogInterface` while you are trying to dismiss an `AlertDialog`

Change :

```
alertDialog.dismiss();
```

to

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```

where dialog is an argument of `onClick` -> `public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this code `alertDialog.show();` to in `createCheckBox()` method after here

```
 alertDialog = checkBuilder.create();
 alertDialog.show();
```

rather than here

```
  private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     createCheckBox();
     alertDialog.show();// remove from here
     }
   }
```

And for positive and negative button click of `AlertDialog` dismiss with

```
 dialog.dismiss():
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog.Builder checkBuilder;

public class ChecckFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener {
private static AlertDialog alertDialog;
private Context context
 @Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     context = this.getActivity();     
   }
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 //other codes....
 View btnCheck = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveNew);
 btnCheck.setOnClickListener(listener);
  }
 private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     createCheckBox();

     }
}
 //Function to create checkBox.
 private void createCheckBox(){
final CharSequence[] checkSequences = {" Low "," Mid "," High "," Very High"};
final ArrayList<Integer> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

 checkBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
checkBuilder.setTitle("Select School Leaving Reason");
checkBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(checkSequences, null, new               DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            itemList.add(indexSelected);
        } else if (itemList.contains(indexSelected)) {
            itemList.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
        }
    }
});

checkBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int str : itemList){
         sb.append(",");    //separating contents using semi colon
            sb.append(str); 
        }
        sb.deleteCharAt(0); //Delete chatacter at 0.
        String string = sb.toString();
     Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Items:"+ sb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    dialog.dismiss();//Called dismiss here but dialog doesnt closes
    }
});
checkBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();  //<--------------------------------error found--
    }
});

alertDialog = checkBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with fragments `DialogFragment` is most recommended method to use.

But if you want to stick with Alert Dialog, you should not declare your `createCheckBox()` in your `Fragment` class as `getActivity` sometimes may freeze your fragment and hence `alertDialog` is not dismissed.
To solve this issue declare your `createCheckBox()` method in `FragmentActivity` class as below:

```
private void createCheckBox(){ 
    final CharSequence[] checkSequences = {" Low "," Mid "," High "," Very High"};
    final ArrayList<Integer> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    AlertDialog.Builder checkBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    checkBuilder.setTitle("Select School Leaving Reason");
    checkBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(checkSequences, null, new         DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                itemList.add(indexSelected);
            } else if (itemList.contains(indexSelected)) {
                itemList.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
            } 
        } 
    }); 

    checkBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int str : itemList){
             sb.append(",");    //separating contents using semi colon
                sb.append(str); 
            } 
            sb.deleteCharAt(0); //Delete chatacter at 0.
            String string = sb.toString();
         Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Items:"+ sb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        alertDialog.dismiss();//Called dismiss here but dialog doesnt closes
        } 
    }); 
    checkBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();//Called dismiss here too but dialog doesnt closes
        } 
    }); 

    alertDialog = checkBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
//*************************Method for  selecting dialog*******************************//

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case ALERT_DIALOG:
                createCheckBox(0);
                return alertDialog;         
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Now from your activity class call createCheckBox() method like this:
    begin(delete begin end)

```
public class ChecckFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemSelectedListener { 
    private static AlertDialog alertDialog;
    private final int ALERT_DIALOG = 0;
    private Context context
     @Override  
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         context = this.getActivity();     
       } 
    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //other codes.... 
     View btnCheck = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveNew);
     btnCheck.setOnClickListener(listener);
      } 
   private OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
         getActivity().showDialog(ALERT_DIALOG); //Calls your createMethod from activity class.
         } 
    }   
}
```

This might be helpful to you.